# jest: error message lost with Promise

Tags: javascript, es6-promise, jestjs

**Edit**: this is the same problem as describe here: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2980 . `done()` is not called because of the error, so jamsin timeout is reached. That's ok. But what is not ok is that jasmin/jest should report the error that happende.

Note: example source code can be found
[here](https://github.com/dfroger/issue/tree/master/jest-promise-error).

Consider the following function, which creates a `Promise`, and invokes the
`done` callback when the promise is resolved:

```
// file: foo.js

function foo(done) {
    const p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            //const xxx = 2;
            resolve(xxx);
        }, 100);
    });
    p.then(data => {
        console.log(data);
        done()
    })
}

exports.foo = foo;
```

It contains an error: the `xxx` variable is not defined, so a error must
raised.

If I run import this function and execute it in a script:

```
// file: index.js

const foo = require('./foo').foo;

foo(() => {});
```

and run the script with `node v8.6.0`:

```
node index.js
```

I get the expected error (`ReferenceError: xxx is not defined`):

```
/home/dfroger/repo/dfroger/issue/jest-promise-error/foo.js:5
            resolve(xxx);
                    ^

ReferenceError: xxx is not defined
    at Timeout.setTimeout [as _onTimeout] (/home/dfroger/repo/dfroger/issue/jest-promise-error/foo.js:5:21)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:469:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:304:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:264:5)
```

If now I write a unit test for `foo`:

```
// file: foo.test.js

const foo = require('./foo').foo

describe('async', () => {
    it('run foo', done => {
        foo(done);
    });
});
```

And run it with `jest v21.2.1`:

```
./node_modules/.bin/jest
```

I no more get the error message about `xxx being not defined`:

```
  async
    ✕ run foo (5004ms)

  ● async › run foo

    Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.

      at node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queue_runner.js:64:21
      at ontimeout (timers.js:469:11)
      at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:304:5)
      at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:264:5)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        5.574s, estimated 6s
Ran all test suites.
```

Did I miss used `jest`? Is it a `jest` bug? How can I make sure that `jest`
always correctly report error messages?

Answer (score 0):

You havent added a catch block to your promise; Though I can't test it all out, i believe this is your issue;

// file: foo.js

```
function foo(done) {
    const p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            //const xxx = 2;
            resolve(xxx);
        }, 100);
    });
    p.then(data => {
        console.log(data);
        done()
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(`Following error occured : ${err}`);
  });    
}

exports.foo = foo;
```